# My event handler is never called because the original event is raised in another event handler?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

The event handlers in my parent class are never called though the events are raised in the child class.

The Code:

```
Public Class childForm

    Public Event checkboxchangedEvent(ByVal checkbox1 As Boolean, ByVal checkbox2 As Boolean)
    Private Sub checkboxchanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        RaiseEvent checkboxchangedEvent(CheckBox1.Checked, CheckBox2.Checked)
        End Sub
End Class

Public Class ParentForm

Friend WithEvents cf As childform = New childform

 Private Sub cf_checkboxchanged(ByVal checkbox1 As Boolean, ByVal checkbox2 As Boolean) Handles cf.checkboxchangedEvent

        My.Settings.checkbox1 = checkbox1

        My.Settings.checkbox2 = checkbox2
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the child form is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this as an alternative method of setting up the event handler,

```
Public Sub ShowChildForm()
     Dim frm as New childform
     AddHandler frm.checkboxchangedevent, AddressOf cf_checkboxchanged
     frm.ShowDialog()
     RemoveHandler frm.checkboxchangedevent, AddressOf cf_checkboxchanged
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is timing.  Try explicitly creating the form and adding the handlers in `ParentForm`'s `Load` event handler.  (This is all typed from memory and untested so event names/signatures for the `Load` event may be incorrect.)

```
Public Class ParentForm
    Friend WithEvents cf As childform

    Private Sub cf_checkboxchanged(ByVal checkbox1 As Boolean, ByVal checkbox2 As Boolean)
        My.Settings.checkbox1 = checkbox1
        My.Settings.checkbox2 = checkbox2
    End Sub

    Private Sub ParentForm_Load(ByVal sender as object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        cf = new childForm()
        AddHandler cf.checkboxchanged, AddressOf cf_checkboxchanged
        cf.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm gonna try to get my own question removed.  When I created a new project with just my posted code it worked.  I still do not know how the almost self contained code could work in one project and not in another but thems the breaks.